# Strange LoDash behavior

Tags: javascript, lodash

With this code:

```
var objects = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}];
var result1, result2;  

result1 = _(objects)
  .filter(_.partialRight(_.has, 'a'))
  .value();

result2 = _(objects)
  .filter(function(o){ return _.partialRight(_.has, 'a')(o);})
  .value();
```

`result1` will be an empty array and `result2` will be `[{'a': 1}]`.
Why?

ps
Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6nhLBtq2id0GSYXVjhcX?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that `filter` takes more arguments, that are being implicitly applied in composition, but not in application:

```
// what it looks like
.filter(_.partialRight(_.has, 'a'))

// what's happening
.filter(function(o,i,xs){return _.partialRight(_.has,'a')(o,i,xs);})
```

See here http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2Gz5vllUufzRvUuhqDQ?p=preview

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with `partialRight`? It attaches  `a` to *the end* of the composed arguments array, that is, after  `o, i, xs`. Which means, `_.has` gets `i` as the second argument.

Comment: @DCoder: `_.partialRight(_.has, 'a')` should return a function expecting for one argument. It seems it can take more than one. Right?

Comment: "should return a function expecting for one argument" --- should it? It returns a function that accepts any number of arguments that are appended by partially applied. The actual call looks like: `_.has(o,i,xs, 'a')`. Compared to `_.has(o, 'a')` (that's why the calls return different results actually)

Comment: @zerkms: yes, that sounds right, I got confused. I was disregarding "right", as my functions usually take the arguments in the opposite order, so I'd do `.filter(has('a'))`, where `has` is curried.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an addition to the [@elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs)' [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26082960/251311):

That's how you could do what you want without creating an anonymous function:

```
result1 = _(objects)
  .filter(_.compose(_.partialRight(_.has, 'a'), _.identity))
  .value();
```

Explanation:

The `_.compose()` function accepts the number of function references and applies them one by another, passing the result of execution from previous function to the next. And the `_.identity()` function returns the first passed argument.

So if we unwrap the `_.compose(_.partialRight(_.has, 'a'), _.identity)` expression it will look like:

```
function (a, b, c) {
    return _.partialRight(_.has, 'a')(_.identity(a, b, c));
}
```

Online demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/kU3MkrfSJol9c9JbGBqo?p=preview

References:

- http://lodash.com/docs#compose
- http://lodash.com/docs#identity